# A popup notification balloon after comment reply in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Now I am doing a forum like website. I wan to do something like after the member reply the post and the homepage will display a popup notification balloon and show out the number of notification that the member are unread. May I know how can I make it? I am using asp.net and C# in my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PopupControl in AJAX:

```
<ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender ID="PopEx" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="DateTextBox"
    PopupControlID="Panel1"
    Position="Bottom" />
```

Here is a link that explains it further.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to enable communication across browser sessions. For something like this I'd suggest SignalR http://www.asp.net/signalr.

It allows you to use javascript to broadcast messages and listen for messages sent from the server. You can also hook into it via code behind. So, say user X responds to user Y's post. After you do what you need to do to save the post to the database, you add a bit of code that broadcasts to user X "Hey! Someone commented on your post. Check it out!".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It look can work. But I don't have any idea on signalr because im beginner in C#. Can have further explain on it? Thank you very much